# The fourier transform preserves norms for a square-integrable function proof

Tags: fourier-analysis, normed-spaces, fourier-transform

Can you provide proof for "The Fourier transform preserves norms for a square-integrable function"?

Comment: Did you prove the Fourier inversion theorem for some kind of functions ? Or just for the Gaussians it works too. Then we use the density in $L^2$.

Comment: No I haven't. this is one of the questions in Linear Integral Equations by Dr.Kanwal that I haven't been able to solve. If you can provide a link to help solve this, you have my thanks.

Answer (score 4):

- The Schwartz functions are dense in $L^2$: because for $f\in L^2$ for $T$ large $\|f-f 1_{[T,-T]}\|_2$ is small and for $n$ large $\|f 1_{[T,-T]}-n e^{-\pi n^2 x^2}\ast f 1_{[T,-T]}\|_2$ is small ($\ast$ is the convolution).
- The finite linear combination of Gaussian functions $e^{-a (x+b)^2+icx}$ are dense in the Schwartz functions thus in $L^2$ (do a convolution with $n e^{-\pi n^2 x^2}$ again and approximate the Riemann integral by a Riemann sum)
- For such a finite linear combination of Gaussians functions let $(Wg)(y)=\int_{-\infty}^\infty e^{-2i\pi xy}g(x)dx,(W^* g)(y)=\int_{-\infty}^\infty e^{2i\pi xy}g(x)dx$, the known Fourier transform of the Gaussian gives that $W^* Wg =g$. Also it is easily seen that $\langle Wg,h\rangle=\langle g,W^*h\rangle$ thus $$\|Wg\|_2^2=\langle Wg,Wg\rangle=\langle g,W^* Wg\rangle=\langle g,g\rangle = \|g\|_2^2$$
- Take a sequence $g_n$ of such  finite linear combination of Gaussians such that $\|f-g_n\|_2\to 0$ then its Fourier transform $Wf$ is defined as the limit in $L^2$ of the sequence $Wg_n$ (which is Cauchy by the previous result) so it is by definition that $\|f\|_2=\|Wf\|_2$.

It works the same way when replacing the Gaussians by any kind of functions for which you proved the Fourier inversion theorem (for example the functions such that $h,h'\in C^0\cap L^1$, from the Dirichlet kernel).